# Redirect to any url right after downloading file from server using php

Tags: php

Header("location:index.php"); is not working for me.

$file is path of file.

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    readfile($file);

    header("location:index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: show us an error you are getting...

Comment: I had similar problem... solved by adding ob_start(); and  ob_end_flush();

Comment: You can try using javascript's `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Comment: i don't have any error. i want when script downloads file. right after that i make jump to another page

Comment: it does download the file and don't redirect to index page.

Comment: You need to reverse the logic. Instead of Trying to "offer download, then redirect", you should first redirect, and then offer the download. Other solutions are complicated and require ajax and flags persisted on the server to watch the status of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser makes a call to the server. The server responds with headers ("I will be sending a file") and sends the content. Browser reads headers and instead of showing the new page it offers you to save the file. All further actions are ignored.

If you want both file download and redirect, you have to send the request for download to another container (new tab, new window, iframe) and redirect the main window elsewhere with javascript.